# DRBL hangs after booting

Tags: linux, networking, boot, pxe

I'm trying to restore a lab using a network boot, but unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be working correctly.

The only thing that happens is the my computer boots up using PXE, and I get the an IP, but from there, the entire system just hangs (no output, just a blinking light).

Any insights into why this is happening?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this issue? I'm having the same problem, using Debian 7.2 and the stable version of DRBL in the DRBL repo.

Comment: @WildVelociraptor, i did manage to solve it! (Can't say if it'll do you any good) I upgraded the bios of every machine in the lab, and they all worked!

If it helps, the computers I had were Optiplex 990, using BIOS A03 (pre-upgrade) and are now running A10 (post-upgrade)

Comment: Interesting. I'm using a Dell Precision M4500, and I upgrade the BIOS from A06 to A14, but I still have the same issue. I also can't get the DRBL environment to come up on a Lenovo Thinkpad W530. Thanks for your help though!